# How to use adforn package?

Tags: miktex

I would like to insert a single ornament on the titlepage of my thesis, something like this:

[image]

I have found the `adforn` package on CTAN and it has the exact glyph I was looking for. However, after I load the package in the preamble (`\usepackage{adforn}`) and give out the command for inserting the ornament (`\adforn{21}`, for package usage see http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/adforn/doc/fonts/adforn/adforn.pdf), my document fails to compile with the following error message:

```
Trying to make PK font OrnementsADF at 600 DPI...
Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The OrnementsADF source file could not be found. miktex-makepk
: The application file ttf2pk.exe could not be found.
```

I use MiKTeX on Windows 10. I have checked, the `adforn` package is installed correctly, at least according to MiKTeX. Yet, something is wrong, and the the simplest document can't compile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adforn}
\begin{document}
    \adforn{21}
\end{document}
```

Can you help me find a solution for this? Thank you.

Comment: Did you run `updmap.exe` from the command line?

Comment: It was an error in the miktex installation. It will be fixed in the next update. In the meantime add `\pdfmapfile{=OrnementsADF.map}`

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: on my system, `updmap.cfg` contains a reference to this font (I mean, the distribution file, not my personal `updmap.cfg`).

Comment: @Bernard: Just ran `updmap.exe` as administrator, the problem persists.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thank you, I added `\pdfmapfile{=OrnementsADF.map}` and it worked.

Comment: @lamarr don't run it as admin, run it as user -- user maps wins over admin maps, and if your user map is incomplete you need to update it as user. If it still doesn't work you will have to check for updates. miktex seems to have added the map entry to updmap.cfg.

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, looks as if is now there. It wasn't two or three days ago.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: ran it as user, nothing changed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this problem is due to a regression in MikTeX, which will be fixed in the next update (according to Ulrike Fischer).